# Why is TF IDF output lognormal?

Tags: text-mining, tfidf

I ran a TF IDF algorithm and the result of predicted similarities using cosine similarity is a log-normal distribution.  Is this a feature of the algorithm (e.g., all logit probabilities are log-normal), or might it be a result in my data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s look at the formula used for the calculation of `tf-idf` scores

[image]

You can see a `log` with the `idf` term.
The following answer explains this pretty well.
[log with idf](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161640/understanding-the-use-of-logarithms-in-the-tf-idf-logarithm)